# Using Joi, validating that a boolean is true

Tags: javascript, hapi.js, joi

Is it possible to validate that a boolean is `true` using Joi? I've tried using `allow`, `valid` and `invalid` without any luck.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Have you tried something like this:

```
var schema = Joi.boolean().invalid(false);
```

Using that schema, the following all populate the error property:

```
Joi.validate(false, schema);
Joi.validate('false', schema);
Joi.validate('no', schema);
Joi.validate('off', schema);
Joi.validate(0, schema);
```

Comment: This seemed to work. Not sure what I did incorrectly the first time.

Comment: I do not understand, why truthy() and falsy() did not work. Thanks for your solution!

Comment: I haven't looked at Joi lately, but sometimes within the javascript ecosystem, the terms truthy and falsy are referring to how other (non-boolean) types are coerced in boolean contexts.